# How does hadoop RecordReader identify records

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, recordreader

When processing text file how does hadoop identify records ?
Is it based on newline characters or full stops ?

If I have a text file list of 5000 words, all on single line, separated by space; no new line characters, commas or full stops. How will RecordReader behave ?

e.g. abc pqr xyz lmn qwe rew poio kjkh ascd lkyg ......

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the delimiter in the config with `textinputformat.record.delimiter`.

If it isn't supplied it will fallback to split the lines based on one of the following: `'\n' (LF) , '\r' (CR), or '\r\n' (CR+LF)`.
So your example line will be read as a single record.

You can read through the code of the [LineReader](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.hadoop/hadoop-common/2.7.0/org/apache/hadoop/util/LineReader.java#LineReader.readDefaultLine%28org.apache.hadoop.io.Text%2Cint%2Cint%29), [TextInputFormat](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.hadoop/hadoop-mapreduce-client-core/2.7.0/org/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/input/TextInputFormat.java#TextInputFormat) and [LineRecordReader](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.hadoop/hadoop-mapreduce-client-core/2.7.0/org/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/input/LineRecordReader.java#LineRecordReader) for more details.

Comment: Is there a limit on length ?  I had read that if record spans multiple blocks (InputSplits), hadoop is smart to read it from adjacent block. In my case as there is no '\n' (LF) , '\r' (CR), or '\r\n' (CR+LF)  and it may span multiple blocks will it read through all block and make it one big block ?

Comment: There is a configurable line length limit, but it is set to `Integer.MAX_VALUE` by default. If you don't override that, it will read through blocks until it finds a seperating character.